# How to grant permission to FileSystem.php file

Tags: 8

I navigate to `admin/config/media/file-system` in the drupal admin interface. I get this error

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->mkdirCall() (line 244 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php) .

I granted the permission to sites folder using the following commands `chown -R www-data:www-data sites` and `chmod -R g+rw sites`.
But still the error appears.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure that the owner is `www-data` ?

Comment: @berramou I check the permissions using "ls -al" I found this "drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data      4096 Aug  6 06:06 sites"

Comment: OKay so it's not owner issue, give the /tmp Permission 777 and try ?

Comment: And also check the permissions of your files directory not only sites folder

Comment: @berramou the www/html/sites/default/files permission is "drwxrwxr-x 49 www-data www-data  4096 Aug  2 08:09 files" and I don't have /tmp folder! Should I create empty tmp foler?

Comment: Yeah you should have a directory for temporary files, check in your media configuration what you set as temporary directory

Comment: glad that helped, i will post it as an answer if someone needs it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure that the files directory (*sites/default/files* by default) has the right owner and permissions.
And also directory of temporary files, in general */tmp* if you don't have create one and give it the right permissions.